# Detecting a users presence on webcam in Java

Tags: java, webcam, video-capture

I'm working on a Java application, and I want the program to attempt to detect if a user is looking at a screen or not, or if they are present at the keyboard.

What libraries or programs could I use in Java to use my laptops webcam to record a video feed which can:

1. Detect if a user is present in front of the laptop
2. When a user is present, detecting if they are looking at the screen (head thinner/turned towards screen, or looking away (head wider when turned away)

I want something as simple and lightweight as possible that can adequately achieve the algorithm above.

Thanks.

Comment: This is too complex . Please narrow it down a little bit. show some code etc

Comment: Code from what? The context of my application is irrelevant surely, I am adding a feature which could be used in any application to detect a users presence using the webcam, to change something in the program.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to detect the motion of object.

Have a look at this [webcam-capture](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/)